# Missing SOAP-ENV webservice response header in JBOSS EAP 7.4.3 after migration from 6.4

Tags: soap, jboss, cxf, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

0

I am trying to migrate my application server (JBOSS EAP) from 6.4 to 7.4.3. But, after migration I am getting the below error while hitting my webservices.

Unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling error: unexpected element (uri: ....) Caused by : com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; line number: 0; columnNumber: 0; unexpected element (uri:....)

Thus, I have added -Dcom.sun.xml.bind.backupWithParentNamespace=true system property in my JBOSS server VM argument to resolve above issue. Now, I am getting good responses but the below two lines are missing in my new JBOSS(JBOSS EAP 7.4.3) webservice response.

First Line - **<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>** and

Second Line - **<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV=...>**

But this two lines were present in older JBOSS EAP 6.4 response. Should I need to add any other system property for this. Please help me on this.

Reagrds, Ritesh

Comment: Can anyone please answer on this? I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Hello All, I am still facing the same in JBOSS EAP 7.4.3. But, the same request is working fine in JBOSS EAP 6.4. I wish to get soap env header and XML declaration statement in my new JBOSS response. Please help me.